# Question about the output of sample on a multinomial-dist in Gamble

Tags: racket, probability, probability-distribution

I'm trying to understand how to use `multinomial-dist` in Gamble. From the [Gamble documentation](https://rmculpepper.github.io/gamble/dist.html#%28def._%28%28lib._gamble%2Fmain..rkt%29._multinomial-dist%29%29):

> Represents a multinomial distribution. The support consists of vectors of the same length as weights representing counts of n iterated samples from the corresponding categorical distribution with weights for weights.

So if I understood correctly writing `(define test (multinomial-dist 100 (vector 50 40 10)))` defines a multinomial distribution in which, out of 100 samples, outcome 1 appeared 50 times, outcome 2 appeared 40 times and outcome 3 appeared 10 times. What I'm struggling to understand is that if I evaluate `(sample test)` I could obtain results like `'#(51 88 100)` and I can't really understand what these numbers mean. I know that probably is an easy question, but I really can't find the answer anywhere else. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think the documentation describes what's happening in a nested way, so you have to start at the end of the sentence and work backwards. Your `(vector 50 40 10)` is the weights for "the corresponding _categorical_ distribution", from which you need "counts of n iterated samples" as input to `multinomial-dist`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried `(define test (multinomial-dist 3 (vector 0.7 0.1 0.2)))` and by evaluating `(sample test)` I obtained as output `'#(3, 1, 3)`, could you help me interpreting what does this means? Thank you kindly